# st_read query with openGDB layers

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I would like to load in several layers from a OpenFileGDB file, but am having trouble with the query component of st_read.

The problem I'm having is that I have 10 layers in a OpenFileGDB that are prohibitively large to open in their entirety.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried following the examples from st_read, but I end up with an error message saying the geom is missing, or that I'm missing a dsn, or I get a string of errors.

EDIT::

```
p2018 <- st_read("vri2008_vri2018.gdb", layer="veg_comp_lyr_r1_poly_2018",  query("SELECT REFERENCE_YEAR from veg_comp_lyr_r1_poly_2018  where SOURCE_TYPE = 'BW'"))
```

This works, while the following does not.

```
p2018 <- st_read("vri2008_vri2018.gdb", layer="veg_comp_lyr_r1_poly_2018",  query("SELECT REFERENCE_YEAR from veg_comp_lyr_r1_poly_2018", gdb))
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying?

Comment: This works for me, where `gdb` is a path to a file GDB folder: `d = st_read(gdb, "RI_Wetlands_Project_Metadata",query="SELECT * from RI_Wetlands_Project_Metadata where SOURCE_TYPE = 'BW'")`

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks! That is super helpful. Would it be reasonable to put a vignette in sf to talk about how to query different data types/syntax?

Comment: I don't see how this is much different to the examples in the help for `st_read`. Without knowing exactly what you did that failed its hard to know how you misunderstood the examples. Can you edit your Q and show your failings?